# Magento Category Pages: Change layout of specific categories from grid mode to list mode

Tags: xml, layout, magento

I want some category pages to be in the list mode and to start with 30 items displayed but I want another category page to be in grid mode and with fewer items displayed.

I understand that I can do this by updating the custom layout xml through the admin panel, but I'm not sure what the exact XML would be.

Comment: It is more like you should perform a customization, with observing of events and overriding few classes in Magento. Seems somewhere in my archives, I have such a module. If I find it, I'll let you know. But there was only customization with listing modes, that was able to be configured. But I am sure you can perform something similar for product list page size.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out. The Magento class is missing a method for setting the mode, you can only set the mode via the GET parameters to the page. so I created a new module that overrides it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was to create a module that overrides the Toolbar class which is what controls the grid/list view of the catalog and the number of items to display.

The specific class to override is called `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`. Clone the file and add the following method to it:

```
/**
 * Sets the current View mode (grid, list, etc.)
 *
 * @param string $mode
 */
public function setCurrentMode($mode)
{
    $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', $mode);
}
```

You also need to create a config.xml file for it.

```
<!-- app/code/local/Example/Catalog/etc/config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <product_list_toolbar>Example_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Now, in the admin panel, to change the layout of a category, go to *Catalog > Manage Categories* and select the category that you wish to change. Go to the *Custom Design* tab and in the field labelled *Custom Layout Update*, enter the following XML code:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="setCurrentMode">
    <mode>list</mode>
  </action>
</reference>
```

Of course, remember to flush the layout caches of Magento or your change won't appear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the function to a local copy of the file and did not bother with a proper 'module' approach, worked fine for me and I can still manage my upgrades sensibly.

Comment: Cool, just make sure you check out the differences between the files everytime you upgrade. My method uses a cloned file from Magento's core code so that may change during an upgrade :S

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late, but this works even without rewrites directly via the layout XML or the "Custom Layout Update" section in admin:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setData"><key>_current_grid_mode</key><value>list</value></action>
</reference>
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25803228/1918829

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the list.phml and rename it to grid.phtml and then:

change

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

to

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='list'): ?>
```

and then add the block to CMS page:

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="152" template="catalog/product/grid.phtml"}}
```