# Set "List / Grid" default view mode in catalog.xml for category view

Tags: magento

I'm trying to do my category view display products in list or grid mode as default.

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Here is the code that I have inside `<catalog_category_layered>` and in `<catalog_category_default>`. Know anyone how to do it? I was googling to much time and didn't found a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in the layout XML or the "Custom Layout Update" section in admin with the following xml:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setData"><key>_current_grid_mode</key><value>list</value></action>
</reference>
```

Be sure, the toolbar block name was set in the product list block like this:

```
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you want to override default display mode for a particular category.

Comment: wish i could up vote 2x .. i installed an extension that hijacked the `setToolbarBlockName`.. you answer helped my second issue, making sure i used the overridden `setToolbarBlockName` name

Answer (score 10):

You can set grid or list from backend

> System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend->List mode

Comment: thanks but i'd like to do it by code, from xml layouts, like those functions to put max number of products

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to use the method described by @rengaw83, you will not be able to switch between modes in that category anymore. For instance, if you click on "Grid", the mode will not change to grid mode.

To be able to switch modes and just set the default view mode in a category via a custom layout, you need to override the core Toolbar block, and add the following method to it:

```
/**
 * Sets the current View modes (grid, list, etc.)
 *
 * @param array $modes
 */
public function setCurrentModes($modes)
{
    $this->_availableMode = $modes;
    $modes = array_keys($this->_availableMode);
    $defaultMode = current($modes);
    $mode = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getModeVarName());
    if ($mode) {
        if ($mode == $defaultMode) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsDisplayMode();
        }
    } else {
        $mode = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
    }

    if (!$mode || !isset($this->_availableMode[$mode])) {
        $mode = $defaultMode;
    }
    $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', $mode);
}
```

Then you will be able to set modes in custom layout tab like that:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setCurrentModes">
        <modes>
            <list>List</list>
            <grid>Grid</grid>
        </modes>
    </action>
</reference>
```

for default list mode, or

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setCurrentModes">
        <modes>
            <grid>Grid</grid>
            <list>List</list>
        </modes>
    </action>
</reference>
```

for default grid mode. Or you even can pass only one mode to set only grid or list mode available.