# Magento: Products List - Changing back to Grid Mode

Tags: magento

I'm trying to figure out a way to set the Grid Mode/List Mode back to default, which in this case is Grid Mode. I want someone to be able to use List Mode if they like, but only on that page. Once they go to another page, I want that page to be reverted back to Grid Mode no matter what.

The reason I need this is due to Infinite Scroll seizing to function properly when someone stays on List Mode going from one page to another. This has been the only option to fix it.

Comment: Looks like this has an answer on Magento stackexchange already: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/how-to-make-products-per-page-setting-reset-to-default-on-pageload

Comment: I tried this. I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: I added the block under  <catalog_category_layered> <reference name="product_list">  Is this the right spot?

Comment: The category is layered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reference the `product_list_toolbar`, because the function you want, `disableParamsMemorizing()` is a member of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`.

So your local xml update would look something like:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="disableParamsMemorizing"></action>
        <action method="setData"><key>_current_grid_mode</key><value>list</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Edit: Found another SO question that seemed like it could be similar: [Set "List / Grid" default view mode in catalog.xml for category view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305787/set-list-grid-default-view-mode-in-catalog-xml-for-category-view/25803228#25803228)

Comment: I added this to my local.xml file. No luck.

Comment: This seemed to work for the Sort By, but not the Grid/List Mode.

Comment: You could try the <default> handle instead of <catalog_category_layered>.

Comment: I also found another SO question that suggests you can set the display mode forcibly with the layout XML. (Updated answer). Not sure if this will work for you though, since you still want people to be able to choose sometimes.

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know. Yeah, we did some research and found that people are using it. So we can't just get rid of it. I would love to get rid of it, but it's all up to what the customers want.

Comment: Sorry. None of this worked. Setting the setData just defaults the sort mode to list and keeps it on list mode. Even if I click on grid mode, it will never show grid mode. If I turned the value from list to grid, the opposite will happen and you will never be able to see the products in list mode. I also placed the reference under <default> instead of <catalog_category_layered>. No luck there either.